# Identical .txt files w/ different outputs

Tags: c++, arguments, codeblocks

Using codeblocks, I have written a code that displays an adjacency matrix, BFS and DFS search order, and whether or not graph is bipartite.

The graph is passed as a program argument through main as a .txt file.

I have two identical .txt files with different names and drastically different outputs. I have absolutely no idea why.

for `graph0.txt` 
[image]
I have this output
[image]

For `graphNull.txt`
[image]
I have this output
[image]

With the exception of the file name, the files are identical. I even typed them the exact same way just to make sure. Why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Graph.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
Graph g;
g.load(argv[1]);

cout << endl << "Adjacency Matrix" << endl;
g.display();

g.displayDFS(0);
g.displayBFS(0);

cout << "Bipartite: ";
if (g.isBipartite())
cout << "TRUE";
else
cout << "FALSE";
cout << endl;



return 0;
}
```

Graph.h

```
    #ifndef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H

#include "QueueInt.h"
#include "StackInt.h"

class Graph {

  public:
    Graph();        // constructor
    ~Graph();       // destructor

    // Load the graph from a file
    void load(char *filename);

    // Display the adjacency matrix
    void display() const;

    // Display the depth first search from the given vertex
    void displayDFS(int vertex) const;

    // Display the breadth first search from the given vertex
    void displayBFS(int vertex) const;

    // Determine whether the graph is bipartite or not
    bool isBipartite() const;

  private:
    string fName;
    int numVert;
    int** mat;
    int* visited;
    int* dfs;


    void helperDFS(int vertex, int &counter, int* visited, int* dfs) const;




};

#endif
```

Graph.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

#include "Graph.h"
#include "QueueInt.h"
#include "StackInt.h"

// Constructor
Graph::Graph()
{
    fName = "";
    numVert = 0;

}

// Destructor
Graph::~Graph()
{
    delete mat;
    delete visited;
    delete dfs;
}

// Load the graph from a file
void Graph::load(char* filename)
{
    int numStore;
    fName = filename;
    fstream fin;
    fin.open(filename);
    fin >> numStore;
    numVert = numStore;
    mat  = new int *[numVert];
    int a;
    int b;

    for (int i = 0; i < numVert ; i++){
        //matrix is created
       mat[i] = new int[numVert];

       for (int j = 0; j < numVert; j++){
        mat[i][j] = 0;
       }
    }

        while (fin >> a >> b){
            mat[a][b] = 1;
            mat[b][a] = 1;
        }



}

// Display the adjacency matrix
void Graph::display() const
{

    for (int i = 0; i < numVert; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < numVert; j++){
            cout << mat[i][j] << " ";
        }
    cout << "\n";
    }

}





// Displays the depth first search starting at the given vertex
void Graph::helperDFS(int vertex, int &counter, int* visited, int* dfs) const {
    visited[vertex] = 1;
    dfs[counter] = vertex;
    counter++;

    for (int j = 0; j < numVert; j++){
        if (mat[vertex][j] == 1 && visited[j] != 1){
            helperDFS(j, counter, visited, dfs);
        }

    }
}

void Graph::displayDFS(int vertex) const
{
int counter = 0;
int* visited = new int [numVert];
for(int i = 0; i < numVert; i++){
    visited[i]  = 0;
}

int* dfs = new int [numVert];

helperDFS(vertex, counter, visited, dfs);
cout << "DFS at vertex " << vertex << ": ";
for (int i = 0; i < numVert; i++){
    cout << dfs[i] << " ";
}
}

// Perform breadth first search starting at the given vertex
void Graph::displayBFS(int vertex) const
{
    int v = vertex;
    int vert;
    int bfs[numVert];
    int counter = 0;
    int* visited = new int [numVert];
    QueueInt q;     //empty q
    //create visited array initizalized to false for each vertex
    for (int i = 0; i < numVert; i++){
        visited[i] = 0;
    }
    cout << endl;
    //mark v as visited
    visited[vertex] = 1;
    //add v to queue
    q.enqueue(vertex);
    //process v to array for output
    bfs[counter] = vertex;

    counter ++;

    while(!q.isEmpty()){
     vert = q.dequeue();
     for (int j = 0; j < numVert; j++){

        if (mat[vert][j] == 1 && visited[j]!=1){

            visited[j] = 1;

            q.enqueue(j);
            bfs[counter] = j;
            counter ++;
        }
     }
    }

    cout << "BFS at vertex " << v << ": ";
    for (int i = 0; i < numVert; i++){
        cout << bfs[i] << " ";

    }
    cout << "\n";



}

// Determine whether the graph is bipartite or not
bool Graph::isBipartite() const
{
    bool flag = true;
    int color[numVert];
    //ASSIGN COLOR ELEMENTS TO 0
    for (int i = 0; i < numVert; i++){
        color[i] = 0;
    }
    //ASSIGN CURRENT ELEMENT COLOR 1
    for (int i =0; i < numVert; i++){

    if (color[i] == 0){
        color[i] = 1;

    }
    //ASSIGN ADJACENT ELEMENTS COLOR 2
    for (int j = 0; j < numVert; j++){
        if (mat[i][j] == 1){
            color[j] = 2;
        }
    }
    //FOR ELEMENTS WITH COLOR TWO, CHECK FOR ADJACENCY
    for (int j = 0; j < numVert; j++){
        if (color[j] == 2){
        for (int k = 0; k < numVert; k++){ //will have a self check, but thats not a problem given no self loops
            if (color[k] == 2){
                if (mat[j][k] == 1){
                    flag = false;
                    return flag;
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    //RESET COLORS, RUN AGAIN
    for (int h = 0; h < numVert; h++){
        color[h] = 0;
    }
    }
    return flag;

}
```

QueueInt.h

```
#ifndef QUEUEINT_H
#define QUEUEINT_H

#include <queue>
using namespace std;

class QueueInt
{
 public:

   // Add an integer to the back of the queue.
   void enqueue(int val);

   // Removes and returns an integer from the front of the queue. Aborts the
   // program is the queue is empty.
   int dequeue();

   // Returns but does not remove the integer at the front of the queue. Aborts the
   // program is the queue is empty.
   int front() const;

   // Returns true if the queue is empty.
   bool isEmpty() const;

 private:
   queue<int> queueObj;     // underyling STL queue object
};

#endif // QUEUE_H
```

QueueInt.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

#include "QueueInt.h"

// Add an integer to the back of the queue.
void QueueInt::enqueue(int val)
{
  queueObj.push(val);
}

// Removes and returns an integer from the front of the queue. Aborts the
// program is the queue is empty.
int QueueInt::dequeue()
{
  int val = front();
  queueObj.pop();
  return val;
}

// Returns but does not remove the integer at the front of the queue. Aborts the
// program is the queue is empty.
int QueueInt::front() const
{
  if (isEmpty()) {
    cerr << "Tried to access empty queue --> aborting program" << endl;
    exit(-1);
  }

  return queueObj.front();
}

// Returns true if the queue is empty.
bool QueueInt::isEmpty() const
{
  return queueObj.empty();
}
```

Comment: What is the code in Graph.h and the corresponding source file. Something has to go wrong there, when the matrix size is determined.

Comment: Why would it go wrong though, they are identical? I'll go ahead and upload the lot of it I guess.

Comment: i think the g.load part will be the most interesting one for now. As you can see, the matrix has a completly wrong size.

Comment: is there anyway to ensure that code copies correctly? I have to go in and individually space everything... annoying. Thought there was a hotkey to do this

Comment: My first idea is: maybe there is a problem when you check the end of line? How do you determine the end of you matrix when reading the textfile? With the newline char? Maybe you are missing a new line char in one of your files.

Comment: @Aeonos I have added graph.h and graph.cpp, you can give them a look

Comment: Your `Graph.h` is the same as the `main.cpp`.

Comment: @kennytm fixed !!

Comment: I think it is time for some debugging. Step through the loading process of those two matricies. Check what value is read into numStore and numVert. the first value of graph0.txt seems to be read as 5 and from graphNull.txt seems to be read as 50. I would also look at those two textfiles using a hexeditor, just to be sure, that they are exactly the same and nobody did some nifty control-char magic, just to give you headeaches.

Comment: I run a stripped-down version of the code through Visual Studio (basically only Graph::load() and Graph::display() kept) with the same input and it works as expected for me. I even created 2 files with the name "graph0.txt" and "graphNull.txt". I played around with the input trying to achieve your "graph0.txt" result by inserting whitespace at the front, encoding the file as UTF-8 and UTF-16 but it only crashed the program. Agreeing that you should single-step through it with a debugger.